# Magento 2 failed payment cart cancels

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

When someone places an order on Magento 2 with viva wallet it cancels the order if the payment fails, can this code be changed so it doesn't cancels the order but redirect to payment failed but keeps the original cart so the customer can just change payment method or try a different card without having to add the item back in the cart

```
<?php

namespace Ced\VivaPayments\Controller\Viva;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action as AppAction;
use Exception;

class Callback extends AppAction
{
/**
* @var \Ced\VivaPayments\Model\PaymentMethod
*/
protected $_paymentMethod;

/**
* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
*/
protected $_order;

/**
* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
*/
protected $_orderFactory;

/**
* @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
*/
protected $_orderSender;

/**
* @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
*/
protected $_logger;

private $_messageManager;


/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
* @param \Ced\VivaPayments\Model\PaymentMethod $paymentMethod
* @param Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender
* @param  \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
*/
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
\Ced\VivaPayments\Model\PaymentMethod $paymentMethod,
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,    
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {

    $this->_paymentMethod = $paymentMethod;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->_client = $this->_paymentMethod->getClient();
    $this->_orderSender = $orderSender; 
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;   
    $this->_logger = $logger;       
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    try {   
        $this->_success();
        $this->paymentAction();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->_failure();
    }
}

public function getOrderId(){
    return $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getLastRealOrderId();
}

protected function paymentAction()
{
    $payment_order = $this->getRequest()->getParam('s');
    $transactionId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('t');

    $OrderCode = $payment_order;    
    $Lang = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lang');
    $order_id = $this->getOrderId();
    $update_order = $this->_objectManager->create('Ced\VivaPayments\Model\VivaPayments')->load($OrderCode, 'ordercode');
    $this->_loadOrder($order_id);

    $MerchantID = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('payment/paymentmethod/merchantid');

    $APIKey =  $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('payment/paymentmethod/merchantpass');

    $request = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('payment/paymentmethod/transaction_url');

    $getargs = '?ordercode='.urlencode($OrderCode);

    $session = curl_init($request);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $request . $getargs);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $MerchantID.':'.$APIKey);
    $curlversion = curl_version();
    if(!preg_match("/NSS/" , $curlversion['ssl_version'])){
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "TLSv1");
    }

    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    try {

        if(is_object(json_decode($response))){
            $resultObj=json_decode($response);
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($resultObj->ErrorCode==0){
        if(sizeof($resultObj->Transactions) > 0) {
            foreach ($resultObj->Transactions as $t){
                $TransactionId = $t->TransactionId;
                $Amount = $t->Amount;
                $StatusId = $t->StatusId;
                $CustomerTrns = $t->CustomerTrns ;
                $message = "Transactions completed Successfully";
                $update_order->setOrderState('paid')->save();
            }
        } else {
            $update_order->setOrderState('failed')->save();
            $message = 'No transactions found. Make sure the order code exists and is created by your account.';
        }
    } else {
        $update_order->setOrderState('failed')->save();
        $message = 'The following error occured: <strong>' . $resultObj->ErrorCode . '</strong>, ' . $resultObj->ErrorText;
    }

    if(isset($StatusId) && strtoupper($StatusId) == 'F')
    {   

    //BOF Order Status
    $orderComment = 'Viva Confirmed Transaction<br />';
            $orderComment .= 'TxID: '.$transactionId.'<br />';

    $newstatus = '';
    $newstatus =  $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('payment/paymentmethod/order_status');
        if(!isset($newstatus) || $newstatus == ''){
                $newstatus = 'pending';
            }

    if($newstatus =='complete'){
                $this->_order->setData('state', "complete");
                $this->_order->setStatus("complete");
        $this->_order->setBaseTotalPaid($Amount); 
        $this->_order->setTotalPaid($Amount);
                $history = $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($orderComment, false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);

            } else {
                $newstate = $newstatus;
                $this->_order->setData('state', $newstate);
                $this->_order->setStatus($newstate);
        $this->_order->setBaseTotalPaid($Amount); 
                $this->_order->setTotalPaid($Amount);
                $history = $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($orderComment, false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
            }
    //EOF Order Status

    $this->_order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(true)->setEmailSent(true)->save();
    $this->_orderSender->send($this->_order, true);

    $this->_registerPaymentCapture($TransactionId, $Amount, $message);
        $redirectUrl = $this->_paymentMethod->getSuccessUrl();
        $this->_redirect($redirectUrl);
    }
    else
    {

        $this->_createVivaPaymentsComment($message);
                $this->_order->cancel()->save();
        $this->_messageManager->addError("<strong>Error: </strong>" .__('Your transaction failed or has been cancelled! Please Try an alternative payment card.'). "<br/>");
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

    }   

}

protected function _registerPaymentCapture($transactionId, $amount, $message)
{
    $payment = $this->_order->getPayment();


    $payment->setTransactionId($transactionId)       
            ->setPreparedMessage($this->_createVivaPaymentsComment($message))
            ->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(false)
            ->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
            ->registerCaptureNotification(
                $amount,
                true 
            );

    $this->_order->save();

    $invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice();
    if ($invoice && !$this->_order->getEmailSent()) {
        $this->_orderSender->send($this->_order);
        $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment(
            __('You notified customer about invoice #%1.', $invoice->getIncrementId())
        )->setIsCustomerNotified(
            true
        )->save();
    }
}

protected function _loadOrder($order_id)
{
    $this->_order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

    if (!$this->_order && $this->_order->getId()) {
        throw new Exception('Could not find Magento order with id $order_id');
    }
}

protected function _success()
{
    $this->getResponse()
         ->setStatusHeader(200);
}

protected function _failure()
{
    $this->getResponse()
         ->setStatusHeader(400);
}

protected function _createVivaPaymentsComment($message = '')
{       
    if ($message != '')
    {
        $message = $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($message);
        $message->setIsCustomerNotified(null);
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: okay cool. and what is your question? we can not provide support for Ced_VivaPayments. ask the developer for support

Comment: Well well @PhilippSander You didnt get this. Developer himself asking question ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you canceled the order:

> $this->_order->cancel()->save();

In that case, you can use reorder functionality. [Check here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/AbstractController/Reorder.php#L56)

```
/* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
$cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    try {
        $cart->addOrderItem($item);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        // add your custom logic
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // add your custom logic
    }
}

$cart->save();
```